# numpy.dot is slow yet blas and lapack are installed, how to fix?

Tags: python, numpy, installation, lapack, blas

I am running on `ArchLinux`, my python version is `2.7.8` and both `BLAS` and `LAPACK` are installed:

```
% pacman -Qs blas; pacman -Qs lapack
local/blas 3.5.0-1
    Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms
local/lapack 3.5.0-1
    Linear Algebra PACKage
```

Numpy has been installed through `sudo pip2 install numpy` and it confirms that it sees both `BLAS` and `LAPACK`:

```
>>> numpy.show_config()
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Yet my speed test for the `np.dot` operation is well over 30 seconds when I know that on a similar machine it runs well under 10 seconds. How to fix the speed issue? Have I missed something when installing numpy with `BLAS` and `LAPACK` support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, here is the whole story. First, the initial setup was slow because `BLAS` is a *reference implementation* which is not designed to be fast. I repeat, as of today, the package `blas` in the ArchLinux Extra repository is the reference implementation. For details, see the `Presentation` section [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).

Secondly, there are optimized versions of `BLAS` (quite a few, actually: ATLAS, OpenBlas, Goto BLAS, MKL and many more, no doubt). They are rather tricky to install. I ended up installing OpenBlas, here is a step-by-step overview of doing that on ArchLinux:

1. Install the `openblas-lapack` [package from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/openblas-lapack/)
2. Install the `python2-numpy-openblas` [package from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python2-numpy-openblas/) As I understand it, it differs from the ordinary `python2-numpy` package by the `site.cfg` configuration file, which instructs `numpy` to be searching for the `openblas` libraries we've installed on step 1.

These actions solved the problem for me, the speed is now much better -- under 1 second for the test I mentioned in the question. Also numpy shows it has been compiled with openblas:

```
>>> np.show_config()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

I believe that the process of setting up `openblas` oriented `numpy` for `python3` looks very similar.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to build 'numpy' from source and link it with BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: Thank you but that is exactly what `sudo pip2 install numpy` does: it gets the `numpy` package, configures it, builds and installs. My next code exerpt shows that `numpy` knows about `BLAS` and `LAPACK`.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that my `BLAS` is actually a reference implementation, not an optimized one. It can bee inferred from reading the `Presentation` section [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)

Comment: @all3fox, You may want to have a look at `ATLAS`. http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net. ATLAS tries to bootstrap a fast `BLAS` implementation tailored to your system.

Comment: @cel thank you, I have been trying to compile it but I cannot switch throttling off for an hour now.